# How to authorize application for Twitter

Tags: php, oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth

I registered a new application with Twitter at https://dev.twitter.com/apps/, as I have done many other times....

On my application registration page under the "Details" tab, I see:

> **Your access token**
>
> It looks like you haven't authorized this application for your own
>   Twitter account yet. For your convenience, we give you the opportunity
>   to create your OAuth access token here, so you can start signing your
>   requests right away. The access token generated will reflect your
>   application's current permission level.

On *ALL* of my other registered applications for other Twitter accounts I manage, under "Your access token" (as seen above) I see "Access token" and "Access token secret" listed. If I remember correctly, to generate these values, I simply clicked "Create your access token" at the bottom of this page.

For my new Twitter account, clicking this just brings up a dialog that says:

> Your OAuth access token has been successfully created. Note that this
>   may take a moment to reflect.

Did Twitter recently change something that I should know about?
How can I get my tokens to show up like normal under the "Details" tab???

This is extremely frustrating!

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the "Settings" tab URL to: http://devwww.cmc.edu:1024/plugins/twitter-oauth/connect.php
and updated the "Settings" tab Callback URL to the same.

I then ran and reran the authentication code for the link above.
Eventually, the tokens showed up like normal under the "Details" tab.

I wish Twitter would simply stick with something...instead of changing the behavior every two months!